# Clicking on li item using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webautomation

I'm working on a web automation tool using Selenium and I'm trying to click on a li item within a ul.

I've managed to loop through the ul and print out all the li elements within the ul. But can't seem to click on the correct item. It keeps clicking on the first item.

I'm able to loop through the elements of the list. This is currently what i have

```
        # # Wait for visibility of all elements located by CSS selector
        elements = WebDriverWait(web_driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.aui-list-scroll > ul li")))

        # Check if any element has text 
        for issue_type_element in elements:
            print(issue_type_element.text)
            if issue_type_element.text == pIssueType:
                print("selected" + issue_type_element.text)
                # Perform the desired action if the condition is true
                # WebDriverWait(web_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(issue_type_element)).click()
                time.sleep(1)   
                issue_type_element.click()
                # web_driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-change-request-(cr)")
                # test = WebDriverWait(web_driver,10).until(
                #     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-change-request-(cr)"))
                # )
                # web_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", test)
                # web_driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-change-request-(cr)").click()
                break
```

This is my DOM image
[HTML DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSoC1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix the SELECTOR

Try this:

```
elements = WebDriverWait(web_driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.aui-list-scroll > ul > li")))
```

instead of:

```
elements = WebDriverWait(web_driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.aui-list-scroll > ul li")))
```

Comment: There isn't a difference. My current code is currently able to loop through the entire list's elements and printing them out. The issue is with the issue_type_element.click() which doesn't click on the correct element in the list but rather the first element in the list.

Comment: I'll be able to better help if you provide the URL

Comment: The URL is an internal link. However a image of the HTML DOM is attached to the post

Comment: any idea how i can accomplish it? thanks

Comment: I'm unable to provide you the solution since I can not reproduce the code as it's not complete but probably you should look at the if condition, the fact it always clicks the 1st li tag may be because it pass the condition